# Hide Button onClick to Show Notice Text, then after 5 seconds, Hide Text Again & Re-Show the Button

Tags: javascript

I want to show the **(i)** image as a button and when someone click on it, I want to hide the button and show the **Notice: thanks for your patience!** text, and after 5 seconds I want to re-display the button and hide the text as it was.

```html
<button id="info" onClick="hideText()"><img src="//i.imgur.com/45PUhN3.png"/></button>

<div class="info-hide">Notice: thanks for your patience!</div>
```

I tried with this code, but didn't work:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function hideText() {
    $("#hide").fadeOut(".info-hide");
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```html
<button id="info" onClick="hideText()"><img src="//i.imgur.com/45PUhN3.png"/></button>

<div class="info-hide" style="display:none">Notice: thanks for your patience!</div>

<script>
  
  function hideText() {
    // hides text for 5 secs  
    
    const btn = document.querySelector('#info');
    const infoHide = document.querySelector('.info-hide');
    
    infoHide.style.display = "block"
    btn.style.display = 'none'
    setTimeout(()=>{btn.style.display = 'block'; infoHide.style.display= "none"}, 5000)
    
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you bro @Tamir Nakar , this solution not work too, but sorry because I forgot to mention that I want to run this on Google Site through Embed code

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I just tested it in Google sites, it seems to work. You just have to publish it first. Here is a link to the site I created: https://sites.google.com/view/niceonexxxz/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA

Comment: Done! I didn't use it right, everything works well now, thank you so much @Tamir Nakar for your help

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function hideText() {
      $("#hide").fadeIn()
   setTimeout(() => {
      $("#hide").fadeOut()
  }, 5000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="info" onClick="hideText()"><img src="//i.imgur.com/45PUhN3.png"/></button>

<div class="info-hide" id="hide" style="display: none;">Notice: thanks for your patience!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ivan Moroz , your solution not work too bro, I forgot to mention that I want to run this on Google Site through Embed Code

Comment: I fixed it bro, thank you so much @Ivan Moroz for your help